# How do I remove the "UNKNOWN"/"MAVIC PRO CAMERA" text that appears above my first person view in UXSDKDemo?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am using the DJI Mobile SDK with a Mavic Pro to add extra functionality to the app, but the text  "UNKNOWN" or "MAVIC PRO CAMERA" appears over the first person view. I think this must come from one of the widgets, but I can't track it down. It is not in my layout xml, nor are those strings in strings.xml.  I would like to remove this text, as it is annoying on the FPV. I am using the UXSDKDemo tutorial as a base.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is under the purview of FPVWidget. You either want to

1) Call the method mFPVWidget.setSourceCameraNameVisibility(false)

or

2) set sourceCameraNameVisibility = "false" within dji.ux.widget.FPVWidget in your layout.xml

Source: http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-uilib-api/Widgets/DULFPVWidget.html#dulfpvwidget_setsourcecameranamevisibility_inline

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. I used your 2nd suggestion,  custom:sourceCameraNameVisibility="false".